# setitimer - SIGALRM not emitted

Tags: c++, timer, signals, c++03

I'm running the code below in 2 different environnements : alone and with other binaries. My problem is that my timer set with setitimer works properly alone (with a main and no class) but in the second environnement it reaches 0 and nothing happens at all. No SIGALRM emitted and no reset to *interval*. The goal of my code is to be able to launch threads at each *interval* when I call my start function and stop the timer (and the launch of threads) on the stop function.
My piece of code :

```
Foo::Foo()
{
    signal(SIGALRM, launchThreads);
}

Foo::launchThreads(int signum)
{
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, threadFunc, NULL);
}

Foo::threadFunc()
{
    (...)
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

Foo::start()
{
    itimerval it_val;
    it_val.it_value.tv_sec = 5;
    it_val.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    it_val.it_interval = it_val.it_value;
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &it_val, NULL);
}

Foo::stop()
{
    itimerval it_val;
    it_val.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    it_val.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    it_val.it_interval = it_val.it_value;
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &it_val, NULL);
}
```

I cut some errors checks and code to be easier to read. SIGALRM mask is correctly set on the process while running (cat /proc/nb/status) and no other process launched with mine is using setitimer or SIGALRM (nor catching this signal).
I attached it with gdb and tried to handle the SIGALRM but nothing was printed when the timer reached 0.
A sample of input with the problem :

```
Timer value    : 5-0  
Timer interval : 5-0
Timer value    : 3-349629  
Timer interval : 5-0
Timer value    : 1-152755  
Timer interval : 5-0
Timer value    : 0-0  
Timer interval : 5-0
Timer value    : 0-0  
Timer interval : 5-0
```